# About affine transform (translation )

Tags: graphics, geometry

For affine 4*4 transformation, I saw two representation in different text

one is

```
L T
0 1
```

Another is

```
L 0
T 1
```

L is the linear part, T is the translation part; I am wondering which is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both forms are correct. The first is used in left-multiply matrix by column vector
**ResultVector = Matrix*V** (for example, in OpenGL), and the second - in right-multiply convention with row vector **V*Matrix** (for example, in DirectX)